# WiFi automatically gets disconnected in Ubuntu 20.10 and starts again only on a reboot

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, 20.10

Whenever I start my Linux system, the WiFi works fine for 20-25 minutes and then abruptly gets disconnected. Then it is not able to detect any hotspots nearby and the wifi symbol becomes like this: [WiFi symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlcAo.png)

In the settings, it shows "unavailable"
[WiFi Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfBjq.png)

On running `lshw -C network`, I got this:

```
ankur@ankurkh1:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for ankur: 
  *-generic DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: ff
       serial: 80:91:33:4e:75:e9
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822be driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:140 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b120ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 32:3b:de:72:d8:4a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.223 link=yes multicast=yes
```

The output of `rfkill list all` is as follows:

```
ankur@ankurkh1:~$ rfkill list all
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I also tried `service NetworkManager restart`, but that didn't work as well.